# Windows Event Log Event ID Usage

Tags: logging, nlog, event-log

Implementing logging with nLog & PoshSharp, and wondering what the use of Event ID field should be[image]

This seems to be set from nLog config, so assuming this has to be a static field - how should this field be used when implementing your own logging?

Comment: As far as I know there is no default value set in NLog for this event. Could you please post your NLog.config or config code so we can see what we're dealing with?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320933/set-event-id-per-log-when-writing-to-windows-event-log

Comment: Yep, @Joe is right. Also have a look at https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/EventLog-target